# Python namedtuple as argument to apply_async(..) callback

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm writing a short program where I want to call a function asynchronously so that it doesn't block the caller. To do this, I'm using `Pool` from python's `multiprocessing` module.

In the function being called asynchronously I want to return a `namedtuple` to fit with the logic of the rest of my program, but I'm finding that a `namedtuple` does not seem to be a supported type to pass from the spawned process to the callback (probably because it cannot be pickled). Here is a minimum repro of the problem.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from collections import namedtuple

logEntry = namedtuple("LogEntry", ['logLev', 'msg'])

def doSomething(x):
    # Do actual work here
    logCode = 1
    statusStr = "Message Here"
    return logEntry(logLev=logCode, msg=statusStr)

def callbackFunc(result):
    print(result.logLev)
    print(result.msg)

def userAsyncCall():
    pool = Pool()
    pool.apply_async(doSomething, [1,2], callback=callbackFunc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    userAsyncCall() # Nothing is printed

    # If this is uncommented, the logLev and status are printed as expected:
    # y = logEntry(logLev=2, msg="Hello World")
    # callbackFunc(y)
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to pass a `namedtuple` return value from the async process to the callback? Is there a better/more pythonic approach for what I'm doing?

Comment: *As defined*, your named tuple can be pickled just fine. See [How to pickle a namedtuple instance correctly](//stackoverflow.com/q/16377215)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the case is different for the return value of `namedtuple()` and its `typename` parameter. That is, there's a mismatch between the named tuple's class definition and the variable name you've given it. You need the two to match:

```
LogEntry = namedtuple("LogEntry", ['logLev', 'msg'])
```

And update the `return` statement in `doSomething()` correspondingly.

Full code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from collections import namedtuple

LogEntry = namedtuple("LogEntry", ['logLev', 'msg'])

def doSomething(x):
    # Do actual work here
    logCode = 1
    statusStr = "Message Here"
    return LogEntry(logLev=logCode, msg=statusStr)

def callbackFunc(result):
    print(result.logLev)
    print(result.msg)

def userAsyncCall():
    pool = Pool()
    return pool.apply_async(doSomething, [1], callback=callbackFunc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = userAsyncCall()

    # To see whether there was an exception, you can attempt to get() the AsyncResult object.
    # print c.get()
```

(To see the class definition, add `verbose=True` to `namedtuple()`.)

Answer (score 4):

The reason nothing is printed is that `apply_async` failed silently. By the way, I think this is a bad behavior which just make people confused. You can pass `error_callback` to handle error.

```
def errorCallback(exception):
    print(exception)

def userAsyncCall():
    pool = Pool()
    pool.apply_async(doSomething, [1], callback=callbackFunc,  error_callback=errorCallback)
    # You passed wrong arguments. doSomething() takes 1 positional argument.
    # I replace [1,2] with [1].

if __name__ == "__main__":
    userAsyncCall()
    import time
    time.sleep(3) # You need this, otherwise you will never see the output.
```

When you came here, the output is

```
Error sending result: 'LogEntry(logLev=1, msg='Message Here')'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <class '__mp_main__.LogEntry'>: attribute lookup LogEntry on __mp_main__ failed",)'
```

PicklingError! <del>You're right, `namedtuple` cannot be passed from the spawned process to the callback.</del>

<del>Maybe it's not a more accpetable way, but you can send `dict` as result instead of `namedtuple`.</del>

As Dag Høidahl corrected, namedtuple can be passed. The following line works.

```
LogEntry = namedtuple("LogEntry", ['logLev', 'msg'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My current workaround is a `list`, but I agree that a `dict` might be a better way of handling this. Still, I'm going to hold out a little and see if anyone has a solution that works with `namedtuple`

Comment: I'd argue that this answer is wrong. The reason for the `PicklingError` is not that named tuples cannot be pickled, but that the correct named tuple is not found during pickling.

Comment: @DagHøidahl Thank you for correctness. I didn't dig into `PicklingError` and gave conclusion too quickly. But other parts of my answer is right. :-)

Comment: I agree :-) I've removed my downvote because of your corrections.